# How to approach database processing server side without interaction from a client?

Tags: mysql, database, cron, server-side

I have a system that I'm trying to plan out, but I'm not sure how to attack it.

The system will take input from (hopefully many) clients and store it in a database (MySQL). That's easy (PHP scripts).

The part I'm not sure about is this: At a certain time interval (every five minutes), the server needs to process the data that the clients submitted in the last five minutes, and push the result (basically an average of the inputs) out to the clients that are currently connected (the 'push' part I think I have a plan for...using Socket.IO), along with having these results available for future requests (also not hard with a dynamic XML file with PHP). I'm just not sure how to best approach the timed processing.

My first thought was to have a PHP script called by `cron`, which could work, but I'm not sure if that's really scalable/the best way to go about this (would making a server-side daemon be better? I really have little idea how to go about that).

I pretty much only went that route since PHP is the only server language I know well. I am looking for alternative (hopefully better, meaning faster and less strain on the server) methods to do this, and (since this is a personal project), I am willing to take up learning a new language (Ruby + Rails was the first to pop up in my mind).

Also any improvements any other parts of the system (other than the timed processing) are welcome as well! I'm looking to have expanded to my coding arsenal after this project.

Since I am just planning this, there is no code available to look at (yet!)

Thank you all for your suggestions!

-Esa

Answer (score 1):

Using MySQL you can either use MySQL Event Scheduler: http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/mysql-event-scheduler-352.html

or if you like to have a more generic solution for cron-jobs, you can dig into JobScheduler: http://www.sos-berlin.com/modules/cjaycontent/index.php?id=124&page=osource_scheduler_quickstart_en.htm